# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can identify stuff from a picture?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Sometimes I have a picture of a natural site, or a building, etc. which I don't know but would like to get its name.

So is there an appropriate site in the Stack Exchange network where I can post such questions?

Comment: No, but you might try tineye

Comment: http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/

Comment: @drachenstern a I didn't know tinyeye, but how does it works? I can find the same picture hundreds of time, but how do I know find out what it is?

Comment: _Usually_ the sites that display a picture have some information about it. I mean, I realize it going up on imgur doesn't help you, but when it goes up on wikipedia, that would be helpful. Try reading a few of the "hundreds" of links. You wanted a site where you could do research ... so go do research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Identifying things in pictures isn't a general skill or a job in itself or a community maker. So it wouldn't work as a topic for a Stack Exchange site. Rather, you should have at least a general idea of what kind of stuff is on the picture (e.g. you know it's a mountain and you'd like to know which). Amongst existing sites, you could try

- [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) for a screenshot of a computer game
- [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) for an exotic kitchen utensil
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) for a strange tool
- [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) for a gaming card
- [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for an sf book cover
- [Super User](http://superuser.com) (home/amateur) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (pro) for an odd piece of computer equipment

There currently isn't a site about landscapes and buildings. Look on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for a site proposal on a topic that would interest you, or start a new proposal if there isn't one already and you're keen and knowledgeable on that topic.

Comment: Thanks also for this answer. I tried this time photo.stackexchange.com and they were able to identify my picture within minutes.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I deliberately didn't mention Photo, because they don't make a business of identifying random stuff on photos. But asking a meta-question the way you did was acceptable — you were lucky to be (it seems) the first to do that so you could use this opportunity to show your example.

Comment: Yes that was luck ;) But I get also 1-2 other useful hints where I can do it next time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a proposal for this on Area 51: [Reverse Image Search](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26549/reverse-image-search). It's currently a pretty weak proposal, though, and it doesn't have many followers.

Comment: Probably because 90% of the answers would be for google goggles and tineye? ;)

Comment: ...and now the proposal is gone.

Answer (score 2):

> a natural sight, or a building

[Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) (currently in beta) might appreciate this kind of question.